# Sentry keeps returning nonexistent incident id's

Tags: python, django, error-handling, tastypie, sentry

We have a django project. We use Sentry for collecting info on HTTP 500 errors.

Sentry has an option to add incident information to request header, so you can handle it in your app.

So, we have a mixin for tastypie that looks like that:

```
class Sentry500Mixin(object):
def _handle_500(self, request, exception):

    if not isinstance(exception, TastypieError) and not settings.DEBUG:
        sentry_exception_handler(request=request)
        data = {
            'error_message': 'Sorry, this request could not be processed.',
            'incident': getattr(request, 'sentry', None)
        }
        return self.error_response(request, data, response_class=HttpApplicationError)

    else:
        return super(Sentry500Mixin, self)._handle_500(request, exception)
```

When a 500 error occurs we get responses like this:

```
 {"error_message": "Sorry, this request could not be processed.", 
"incident": {"id": "3459b30f87ea4116a0a2855be576bbb3", "project_id": "5"}}
```

The thing is that if you take this incident id and go to Sentry, there is a good chance that there will be no incident with this id. And no incident that look like this one. I am sure that I am checking the right project and if the incident was not created, logically, Sentry could not return you an ID, but it did.

Any help and ideas are much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think the ID is generated on the client here: https://github.com/getsentry/raven-python/blob/5b5db6f30ede8109cedd04f30c6cfd0e1572628b/raven/base.py#L285 have you checked your logging level for any errors from this method? https://github.com/getsentry/raven-python/blob/5b5db6f30ede8109cedd04f30c6cfd0e1572628b/raven/base.py#L545

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @erik-e explained in a comment, `event_id` is generated on the client.

### UDP protocol has no guarantees.

Are you using the `UDP` protocol? If you are, the `event_id` does not necessarily map to an actual event in Sentry. The router/switch/network equipment may have lost your packet. With UDP there are no guarantees w.r.t delivery, ordering, or duplicate packets.

I am assuming the `HTTP`/`HTTPS` protocols for sentry are over `TCP`.

Solutions:

- double check firewall rules,
- try out other protocols and make sure it is not a problem with the sentry server.

### Why use UDP then?

Some reasons commonly put forward:

- no handshake = it is faster,
- no connection = no problem if connection was to break (e.g. reboot of sentry server).

Comment: so it IS generated on a client, thanks! I've thought about it, because it looks like a hash, but i did not find any mentions in the docs about it. We will check if we are using UDP and try switching to HTTP then, I'll comment if it helps